# CRON not firing jobs on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, cron, find

I have 3 users on my server, 2 of them are for FTP uploads.

I want CRON to fire a job every once in a while that deletes files in a folder called 'subdomain' in their respective home dir if they are X days old or older.

This command, when run in a terminal as the user who owns the dir, works;
`find /home/derakupload/subdomain -mindepth 1 -mmin +1 -delete`

The issues arise with CRON, which refuse to run this command.
I enter CRON using `sudo crontab -e` and have 2 entries right now;

```
* * * * * derakupload find '/home/derakupload/subdomain' -mindepth 1 -mmin +1 -delete
* * * * * derakupload /opt/script/delete_files_older_than
```

The script in the lower job looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
find $HOME/subdomain -mindepth 1 -type f -mmin +1 -delete
```

I have tried to run it at specific times as opposed to just wilfcarding it all, didn't work.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong anymore.

Comment: What's it say in the log? `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. Also using the $HOME variable when running as sudo will most likely look in the user ROOT home, not derakupload. When you're running commands in a script like that you should specify the whole path explicitly.

Comment: @steeldriver Can you write that as an answer? You are correct. Removing the user from the crontab made it fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perennial source of confusion resulting from the difference between system crontabs (`/etc/crontab` and the associated files in `/etc/cron.d`) and user crontabs (including that for the user `root`, usually accessed via `sudo crontab -e`) - from the `DEBIAN SPECIFIC` section of `man cron`:

```
Support  for  /etc/cron.d  is included in the cron daemon itself, which
handles this location as the system-wide crontab spool.  This directory
can  contain  any  file  defining  tasks  following  the format used in
/etc/crontab, i.e. unlike the user cron spool, these files must provide
the username to run the task as in the task definition.
```

If you really need to run the `find` command as user `derakupload`, then you can either do so directly via their own crontab e.g.

```
sudo -u derakupload crontab -e
```

or add it (**with** the user field) to `/etc/crontab`.

Alternatively, if the `find` command can be run as root, simply use root's crontab `sudo crontab -e` but **omit** the user field `derakupload`.