# Edit crontab file in /etc as root user and add a line, Newbie challenged with syntax

Tags: cron, calendar, scheduler

I set up my CRM on-premise. Within CRM set up sync to Google Calendar.  A manual test run within the CRM demonstrates that sync is working.

The CRM implementation guidelines state the following: For Unix/Linux systems, as a root user, edit the crontab file in /etc, and add an extra line at the end

The documentation provides a sample and explanation below:

```
*/5 * * * * <username> cd </srv/www/vhosts/1crm>; </usr/bin/php> scheduler.php
```

where
`<username>` is the username that the web server runs as (usually defaults to 'apache' or ‘wwwrun’),
and where
`</srv/www/vhosts/1crm>` is the path to your 1CRM directory,
and where
`</usr/bin/php>` is the path to your php executable file.

I figure how to edit as root or enter crontab e -u root in Konsole of Kubuntu.

I modify the above as follows:

```
*/5 * * * * www-data cd /var/www/1crm; /usr/bin/php7.4 scheduler.php
```

And gained no result, so what am I missing? Did I get the user wrong or should it be just PHP, or is it picking up the right scheduler.php (presumably the one in the crm directory).  How do I test a cron job, for that matter?  Right now, I am going in the crm and checking if calendar new test calendar items got sync, from google calendar to the crm calendar.

Comment: If you use `crontab -e` (whether with or without sudo) then you *don't* add the user field `www-data` - see for example [CRON not firing jobs on Lubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/900887/178692)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `;`, use `&&`

```
cd /var/www/1crm && /usr/bin/php7.4 scheduler.php
```

You test cron jobs by adding logging.

Add  `>> /var/log/scheduler.log 2>&1` to the end and all prints and error notices will be added to `scheduler.log`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, collectively your answers helped me get it done.  For example, need to edit the crontab in /etc.  While the formatting answers helped as well.